# Extract signal from big gaussian noise

Tags: noise, filtering

I have signal, periodic with amplitude 10 with frequency about 10 kHz. It is hidden in Gaussian noise with standard deviation 100. Some idea how to extract periodic signal?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the frequency of the periodic signal? Is it sinusoidal or just periodic? By the way, Gaussian noise cannot have a maximal amplitude. You should add some more information so people may be able to actually help you.

Comment: Corrected. I added frequency and standart deviation

Comment: Even with the added information, there is little that can be said. What is the _bandwidth_ of the Gaussian noise, and is it white noise over the bandwidth? Or more simply, is the noise a white noise over the _signal_ bandwidth? Or more simply, **how** did you come up with the assessment that the noise has standard deviation 100? With the information that you have given, I would say that you should use a very narrowband filter centered at 10 kHz and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the signal into a matrix containing one period in each row and average down the columns.